# Weird thing about $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k\zeta{(k)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, riemann-zeta

Consider the sum $S=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k\zeta{(k)}$. By a simple manipulation, we can show:
$$
S=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{(-1)^k\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^k}}=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}{\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{r^k}}=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{r}}-1+\frac{1}{r}}=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+1}}=1
$$
But looking at the partial sums $S_n$ we can see that:
$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
n & S_n\\
\hline
2 & 1.644934... \\
3 & 0.442877... \\
4 & 1.525200... \\
100 & 1.500…026… \\
101 & 0.499…987...
\end{array}
$$
Which disagrees with the result. How can one be trapped so easily?

Edit:

And how to show 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{S_n-\frac{(-1)^n+1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
?

Comment: Probably the series is divergent and can be summed to $1$ with some summation method...

Comment: Note too that $\dfrac {S_{2n}+S_{2n+1}}2\to 1$ : the series doesn't converge but... Let's add that $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k(\zeta(k)-1)\to\dfrac 12$ while $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k\to\dfrac 12$ (once 'regularized' by evaluating first $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-a)^k$ with $a<1$) so that their sum...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint.** The series is not convergent since
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty}(-1)^k\zeta(k)\neq 0.
$$ One may recall that
$$
\zeta(k)=\color{red}{1}+\frac1{2^k}+\frac1{3^k}+\cdots.
$$

Answer (score 2):

What is convergent is $$\displaystyle \sum_{i \geq 2} (-1)^i( \zeta(i)-1)=\sum_{k \geq 2}\left( \sum_{i \geq 2} {1 \over (-k)^i} \right)=\sum_{k \geq 2} {1 \over k(k+1)}=\sum_{k \geq 2} {1 \over k(k+1)}=\sum_{k \geq 2} {1 \over k}-{1 \over k+1}= \lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over 2}-{1 \over n+1}={1 \over 2}$$

Yours of course doesn't converge, because the summed terms don't even go to $0$. However, you can easily prove your limit because:
$${1 \over 2}=\sum_{i \geq 2} (-1)^i( \zeta(i)-1)= \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n- \sum_{i=2}^{n}(-1)^i=\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n - {(-1)^n+1 \over 2}$$